# A lightweight music player for Android.

Tags: android, music

I want a fairly simple music player:

**Must haves:**

- Play FLAC.
- Stop music when headphones pulled out.

**What I'm looking for:**

- A similar browsing structure to Spotify. Ie. If you click the artist, you can see all their albums and browse that way.
- Be able to delete albums/songs from the player.
- Browse by file structure.
- Has a widget.

I don't mind paying, but ideally will have a preview before paying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend **Vanilla Music**. It is free and open source, and pretty lightweight. It is available to download from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.blinkenlights.android.vanilla) or [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=ch.blinkenlights.android.vanilla).

It meets all of your requirements:

- Can play MP3, OGG, FLAC or PCM formats
- Option to pause the music when the headphones are unplugged (on Settings > Audio)
- Can browse by artist / album / track, or browse by directories and files.
- Allows deleting albums or songs from within the player.
- Several styles and sizes of widgets to choose from

Comment: maybe also [VLC](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.videolan.vlc) would be interesting, but it is not sooo lightweight...